# How to check various things in different docker repos on bitbucket?

Tags: git, docker, bitbucket

I have a collection of repositories (100+) on Bitbucket. I want to perform sanity checks on them on a monthly basis. Examples of things I'd like to do:

- Look in `composer.lock` to see current versions of dependencies
- See if the files `.gitignore` and `.dockerignore` exists and if they contain `vendor`
- See if `docker-compose.yml` contains a service called test
- See if `bitpucket-pipelines.yml` is configured to run tests and lints
- See if `Dockerfile` fulfills certain requirements
- See if test coverage is above a certain value

etc...

I started tinkering with a list of repos and a script that is looping over it, checking out the relevant files and extracts information from them, and I got some success. But I have the feeling that there must be a much better way to do this.

I don't expect a magic way to do everything I want with a single click, but there must be a better way than a manual bash script for this. I'm looking for a report only. No automatic fixes.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: bitbucket has a [REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/rest/v810/intro/) that will let you get a list of repositories, retrieve file contents without needing to check things out locally, etc. That's probably the place to start.

Comment: @larsks Yep, that's where I started

Comment: Then show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @larsks This is not really a debugging question. What I have so far is basically what I wrote. Let's take the second thing I want to do as an example. What I do there is simply to download those two files and `grep` for vendor.